# ConTeXt: Double or Triple Hyphen are Interpreted inside Verbatim Blocks

Tags: context, verbatim, context-mkiv

For example:

```
\definetyping
  [code]
  [numbering=line,
   bodyfont=small,
   before={\startframedtext[width=\textwidth]},
    after={\stopframedtext}]

\startcode
<--
\stopcode
```

will produce `<` and `–` (en dash), rather than expected double hyphen `--`. Is this a bug? MKIV here.

Comment: Which ConTeXt version are you using?

Comment: @Joseph Wright: `current version: 2013.05.20 02:00`.

Comment: Add the parameter ``style=mono``.
Those “ligatures” (i.e. the ``tlig`` feature) need to be disabled when defining a font.
It doesn’t appear to be possible to do that with the ``style`` key.
Related post by Wolfgang: http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2012/067283.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an issue with ConTeXt shipped with TL 2016 ([Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev3sn.png)).

Comment: @Henri, then perhaps it's better to give the corresponding answer rather than closing as "off-topic".  What kind of "off-topic" do you see in the question?

Comment: @AlexanderShukaev It is a bug which is fixed now.  There were discussions about how to handle such questions on Meta.  I stick with [this opinion](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6002/109).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With current ConTeXt from TeXlive 2016 the example

```
\definetyping
  [code]
  [numbering=line,
   bodyfont=small,
   before={\startframedtext[width=\textwidth]},
    after={\stopframedtext}]

\starttext
\startcode
<--
\stopcode
\stoptext
```

typesets as

[image]

That means the problem has been fixed.